# ArrayOutOfBoundsException error

Tags: c++, arrays, runtime-error

I'm writing a program with java that analyses stock data.
I almost got it working but now it gives me an ArrayOutOfBounds Exception.

```
int n = closingPrices.size();  
        double[][] cParray = new double[n][1];  
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)  
        {  
            cParray[i][1] = closingPrices.get(i);  
        }
```

I hope you can give me help on how to solve this problem..

Comment: What would `cParray[i][0]` be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the size of cParray[i] is 1. It can have only one element with the index [0]

so try    `cParray[i][0] = closingPrices.get(i)`

OR  `double[][] cParray = new double[n][2]`